# How long is the lifetime of Lucene indexes

Tags: indexing, lucene, lucene.net

I have asp.net project in which i added Lucene.net.The searchable data is from DB.On app building I have method which add all the data to the index.
Is there any way to add the data only once and after that only deletes and updates the documents?
How long is the lifetime of the index? Should i add the data every time on app building?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not perfectly clear what you mean with regard to "lifetime."  The data in the index will exist until you delete it.

Yes there are methods for deleting a doc from the index and for updating a doc in the index.

`writer.DeleteDocuments(query)`
`writer.UpdateDocument`

It's probably worth mentioning, that `writer.UpdateDocument` ultimately causes Lucene to delete the document and then to add the new version to the index.  While that is what's happening under the hood, it's still good to call `writer.UpdateDocument` when needing to update a document in the index since shows the intent of the code.

So there is no reason to fully rebuild the index constantly if you have code that can just add new documents as needed, delete documents as needed and update documents as needed.  Lucene supports all of these operations.